# <input type="file"/> posting data as...?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, file-upload

I'm not even sure if this is possible...

Given a form with `<input id="fileinput" type="file" />`, and a valid selected file, can I POST the `value` using `document.getElementById("fileinput").value` in an `XMLHttpRequest` object and expect `$_FILES` to hold the object? If the POST can be reasonably expected to go through, how can I get the file's info?

**Follow Up**

Is it then possible to use a standard `XMLHttpRequest` Object with `FileReader` for uploading a file? Or is this an entirely different can of fish? I'm trying to minimize extraneous code, not repeatedly ask stupid questions.

**Edit - Closing**

Found out it can be done with no issue and few problems using just the rudimentary file API without filereader, though it incorporates filereader for those who have it.

Essentially, `use XMLHttpRequest().upload` to send the `File`. Completely asynchronous; but no joy in IE or Opera, in which case I can fall back to a standard synchronous form or to the iframe fake.

Anyhow, since apparently it can't be done, I think it'll make a great piece of open source to publish. Thanks all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543926/is-it-possible-to-use-ajax-to-do-file-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in HTML5: http://jsfiddle.net/Cjs4G/.

```
document.getElementById("upload").onchange = function(e) { // on file select
    var fr = new FileReader; // reads files

    fr.onloadend = function() {             // when done reading
        alert(fr.result.substring(0, 100)); // alert first part of data
        // or send `fr.result` through AJAX
    };

    fr.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0]); // start reading
};
```

Comment: Good. Doesn't work in Safari, which means I could fall back for Safari using the `iframe` method.

Comment: @stslavik: I believe it does not even work in IE9 so it might not be production-ready yet.

Comment: Probably not. But I'm getting options, which I wasn't getting before (see all answers starting with "No")

Answer (score 1):

No, JavaScript has no access to the files in a `file` `input` field.

Most of the workarounds involve a Flash uploader of some sort, like SWFUpload. There's some neat HTML5 stuff but you'll lose the 50% of the Internet that are IE users.

Comment: Develop for the best, fall back for the rest. What is some of that "Neat HTML5 stuff"... You mean like FileReader?

Comment: See Gmail's drag-and-drop uploader for an example. I tend to develop for most if possible without a significantly reducing functionality.

Comment: Hooray for the status-quo... Advance by pushing the envelope, not waiting for it to be delivered to you.

Comment: I'm not spending my boss's money on doing twice the work to implement the same feature unless there's a good reason.

Comment: I'm not talking about spending your boss's money to do a job; I'm talking about doing your best on time, under budget, and at the bleeding edge. Do it because you dedicate yourself to what you do – the time is going to be spent at one point or another; now or later, it makes no difference to me.

Answer (score 0):

try valums file-uploader

i just implement it like a week ago for ajax image uploading

https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Answer (score 0):

NOPE.

you CANNOT post files ajaxly.

have a look at this question on ways to fake it.

[How to fake ajax file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396682/how-to-fake-ajax-file-upload)

or this one:
[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: Not true. If the browser supports HTML5 file api, it's possible to use AJAX to send the file to the server.

Comment: neato. i haven't seen that. but how many browsers support that?  certainly not IE 8, which is still probably the most commonly used browser.

Comment: It's true that it's not viable to rely on it (yet). I was just stating it's possible. lol